# Find a string in a file name (shell script)

Tags: regex, string, shell

I am trying to use regex to match a file name and extract only a portion of the file name. My file names have this pattern: `galax_report_for_Sample11_8757.xls`, and I want to extract the string `Sample11` in this case. I have tried the following regex, but it does not work for me, could someone help with the correct regex?

```
name=galax_report_for_Sample11_8757.xls
sampleName=$([[ "$name" =~ ^[^_]+_([^_]+) ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[2]})
```

edit:

just found this works for me:

```
sampleName=$([[ "$name" =~ ^[^_]+_([^_]+)_([^_]+)_([^_]+) ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[3]})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a simple case like this, where you essentially have just a **list of values separated by a single instance of a separator character each, consider using `cut`** to extract the field of interest:

```
sampleName=$(echo 'galax_report_for_Sample11_8757.xls' | cut -d _ -f 4)
```

If you're using `bash` or `zsh` or `ksh`, you can make it a little more efficient:

```
sampleName=$(cut -d _ -f 4 <<< 'galax_report_for_Sample11_8757.xls')
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slightly shorter alternative to the approach you used:

```
sampleName=$([[ "$name" =~ ^([^_]+_){3}([^_]+) ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[2]})
```